# Success message appears before form is submitted

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, ado.net

I have 3 stored procedures which I am trying to execute one after the other, and when all completed, I want to query a table and show a success message if that table has a bit data type column is set to 1.

The problem is that the success message appears as soon as the form appears, and I am trying to show the message only at the end of the form submit. In other words, once all 3 stored procedures have executed check a specific field in the first row and if it is a 1 then show message. I am using `TempData` to show the message.

`TempData` html code

```
@if(TempData["AlertMessage"] != null)
{
    <div>
        <strong>Success!</strong> @TempData["AlertMessage"]
    </div>
}
```

Do I need to nest the procedure calls? Why does the message appear by default before the form is submitted? Thank you.

Action method in `HomeController`:

```
public IActionResult TransformTables(TransformTablesModel tfm)
{
    string connectionString = Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"];

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        // First execute the LoadTables stored procedure with the effective date as the expected parameter
        string loadTables_sqlStatement = "pt.LoadTables";
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(loadTables_sqlStatement, connection))
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@Year",
                Value = tfm.Year,
                SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Int
            };
            command.Parameters.Add(parameter);

            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
        }

        // Execute the SetPTList stored procedure with the list of pay tables selected from the pay table checkboxes in the form view
        // First testing with hard coded list of pay tables
        List<string> tables = new List<string>
        {
            "U100","U110","U130","U150","U200","U210","U230","U250","U300","U310","U350","U500","U510","U530","U550"
        };

        string setPTList_sqlStatement = "pt.SetPTList";
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(setPTList_sqlStatement, connection))
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@PayTables",
                Value = tfm.PTList,
                SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Structured
            };
            command.Parameters.Add(parameter);

            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
        }

        // execute the TransformTables stored procedure
        string transFormTables_sqlStatement = "pt.TransformTables";

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(transFormTables_sqlStatement, connection))
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@EffectiveDate",
                Value = tfm.EffectiveDate,
                SqlDbType = System.Data.SqlDbType.Date
            };
            command.Parameters.Add(parameter);

            parameter = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@CalendarHours",
                Value = tfm.CalendarHours,
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int
            };
            command.Parameters.Add(parameter);

            parameter = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@RUSRate",
                Value = tfm.RUSRate,
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Decimal
            };
            command.Parameters.Add(parameter);

            parameter = new SqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@GuamRate",
                Value = tfm.GuamRate,
                SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Decimal
            };
            command.Parameters.Add(parameter);

            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            connection.Close();
        }

        // Finally check if processed field set to 1 in PTCurrent table
        string ptCurrent_sqlStatement = "SELECT TOP 1 Processed FROM pt.PTCurrent";

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(ptCurrent_sqlStatement, connection))
        {
            connection.Open();

            //using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            //{
            //    var processedValue = reader.Read();

            //    if (processedValue)
            //    {
            //        TempData["Message"] = "Update successful!";
            //    }
            //    else
            //    {
            //        TempData["Message"] = "Update not successful!";
            //    }
            //}

            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.Read())
            {
                TempData["AlertMessage"] = "Successfully updated.";
            }

            connection.Close();
        }
    }

    return View();
}
```

Comment: `"SELECT TOP 1 Processed FROM pt.PTCurrent"` does not check anything, it simply fetches the first row, without any given order. If the execution of your sprocs happens sub-second all three calls could be completing. I would add code to break/wait in between each call and inspect the databases manually to confirm each table is in the expected state after each step.

Comment: Thanks for the break/wait tip. For the SELECT TOP ... I'm trying to look at the field titled Processed from the very first row.

Comment: If you need a specific value you need to filter or sort to make sure you get just it back.
`TOP` with no order by does not guarantee any particular order, and while you may often get back the same row you will not every time, unless it just happens that there is only a single row in the table.